# Unable to get include js file

Tags: django

I want to include below js file to my template but unable to do so. It includes rest of links which are not passing values but this is not including because it passing value `v=1.4.0`.

I am new to django please help me out

**js link**

```
<link href="{% static 'djangoapp/light_css_js/light_css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css?v=1.4.0' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**url.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('test1', views.test1, name='profile1'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def test1(request):
    return render(request, 'user.html')
```

**Error**

```
"GET /static/djangoapp/light_css_js/light_js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js%3Fv%3D1.4.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 1832
```

Comment: <link href="{% static 'djangoapp/light_css_js/light_css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css?v=1.4.0' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: Above is the link which 
I am using to include js file

Comment: `.css?v=1.4.0' %}` => `.css' %}?v=1.4.0`